# How remove the gray background from my .png image

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

I'm using the pysimplegui to create my window, but inside that my image even being .png take the gray background.

[image]

thats my .png image:
[image]

with "background color = blue"

[image]

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg


icon = sg.Image("./images/plane.png")

start_column = [
    [icon]
]

layout = [
    [start_column]
]

startWindow = sg.Window("hello", layout, background_color="blue")



while True:
    events, values = startWindow.read(timeout=30)
    if events == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
```

without "background-color = "blue" "

[image]

Comment: Why can't a .png have a grey background?

Comment: What does "even being .png take the gray background" mean?

Comment: @ScottHunter the alpha channel doesn't work, I chose the .png image because of the transparency

Comment: There's no original PNG file in your post. Image with PNG format maybe not with transparency background, it depend on the values of alpha layer.

Comment: @JasonYang I made in inkscape.

Comment: There is nothing to "remove". The Image will show whatever background it's placed on or what the background color is set to in the Image Element.  By default, an Image Element uses the theme's background color - sg.theme_background_color().  https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/#image-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're two background_color, one for `sg.Image` and another one for `sg.Window`.
background_color of `sg.Image` will be `sg.theme_background_color()` if you don't specify the option `background_color`.

The background color will be `'#64778d'` if you also don't specify what theme to use. So you will see background of your PNG will be different as background of window.

You may specify same value of background_color for both of `sg.Image` and `sg.Window`, or all `None` for them.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Image("d:/plane.png", background_color="blue")]]
window = sg.Window("hello", layout, background_color="blue")
print(sg.theme_background_color())
while True:
    event, value = window.read(timeout=30)
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
sg.theme('LightBlue')
```

and remove the (background-color = blue) from my window parametre.

[image]

Not it's the background color that I wanted but it's working for now.